# click event in jQuery UI widget factory using .on()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I'm trying to implement the [simple manipulation](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation) functionality from jQuery UI Tabs.

But instead of having the code outside the widget, I want to have it inside the widget itself.

The "add new tab" is working properly, but I'm having trouble with the click on the close icon inside the tab. I'm not sure how to handle that event using the widget factory.

This is what I've done so far:

JS:

```
$.widget("ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs,
{
    _create: function(event, ui)
    {
        this._super();

        this._on($("span.ui-icon-close"), {
        click: function()
        {
            var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
            $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
            this.refresh();
        }});     
    },    
    addTab: function(text, id)
    {
        var tab = "<li><a href='#" + id + "'>" + text + "</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>";
        var panel = "<div id='" + id + "'>This is new content! </div>";

        this.tabs.parent().append(tab);
        this.panels.parent().append(panel);

        this.refresh();
    },
});


$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

$("#tabs").tabs("addTab", "New Tab", 3);
$("#tabs").tabs("addTab", "Other Tab", 15);
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/drpcgx0f/2/

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is an actual click event where you can perform your magic, then this can be done by changing this line:

```
var tab = "<li><a href='#" + id + "'>" + text + "</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>";
```

to this:

```
var tab = $("<li>").html("<a href='#" + id + "'>" + text + "</a>");
var close = $("<span>")
              .addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-close")
              .attr("role","presentation")
              .text("Remove Tab")
              .on("click", function() {
                // do whatever you want to do onclick
              });
tab.append(close);
```

Comment: Not the solution I expected but this will do the job. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

```js
$.widget("ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs,
{

    _create: function(event, ui)
    {
      this._super();

  this._on($("span.ui-icon-close"), {
      click: function()
      {
        var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
        $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
        this.refresh();
      }});     
    },    
    addTab: function(text, id)
    {
        var tab = "<li><a href='#" + id + "'>" + text + "</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>";
        var panel = "<div id='" + id + "'>This is new content122121212! </div>";
        
        this.tabs.parent().append(tab);
        this.panels.parent().append(panel);
        
        this.refresh();
    },
    removeTab: function(eve)
    {
    $(eve).remove();
// Refresh the tabs widget
  $("#tabs" ).tabs( "refresh" );
    }
});


$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

$("#tabs").tabs("addTab", "New Tab", 3);
$("#tabs").tabs("addTab", "Other Tab", 15);

$(document).on('click', '.ui-icon-close', function (e) {
  $("#tabs").tabs("removeTab", e.target.offsetParent);
});
```

```css
  #tabs li .ui-icon-close { float: left; margin: 0.4em 0.2em 0 0; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to solve it within the widget, without having code from outside.

Comment: Oops will update soon...Please look at this link.it might be help you http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation  :)